# bootsrap - keeping IMG same size and centered for XS

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, image-resizing

how would i go about keeping an IMG the same size and having it stay centered for only size XS in bootstrap?

My code is identical to this: http://jsfiddle.net/dpvarcfe/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0">
    <img
        src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2813/9093733888_79ccacf171_z.jpg"
        alt="pic" class="img-responsive img-circle">
</div>
<div
    class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
```

I tried to add a min-height and min-width to the IMG, but it loses its centering.
You can see that when you shrink the browser, the IMG can get really tiny.
How can I stop it from shrinking?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you are using `img-responsive` class, and because of that, image respond to size changing. Go with custom size for image, like `img { width: 300px; }`, or what ever size you want, and remove `img-responsive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for and if not, what that is missing. I made used of paddings rather than offsets to ensure that the text content does not take up the entire space of the column.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid conle">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 sizes">
        <img
            src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2813/9093733888_79ccacf171_z.jpg" height =100px;
            alt="pic" class="img-circle">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 sizes">
        <h3>Hello World!</h3>
        <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
            qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.conle {text-align:center;  }
.sizes {padding-left:5%; padding-right:5%;}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxRaoo

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work because at full screen resolution the div's are still stacked, I need them to be next to each other at full res, and only stack at size XS (<768px).  I'll try playing around with it though.

Comment: also it doesn't have to be an IMG, i could do a bg-image in a div if that's easier. It seems like there'd be official bootstrap code for this so I wouldn't have to use any custom classes, but I can't find anything for it.

Comment: I have changed the codepen to make them next to each other @ full res and stack @ size XS.

Comment: @GhostEcho Does this suit you?

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. Wrapping the IMG in its own `<div>` makes it much more manageable. Thanks!

Comment: @GhostEcho No probs! Thanks!